# Limit the images an editor in the wagtail admin sees to only those they uploaded?

Tags: wagtail

I have the Wagtail admin set up so that editors may only add and edit Blog pages that they create. The issue is that when using the image chooser to select images, they are able to see every image uploaded to the site. I need them to see only the images they uploaded.

My site is setup so that my target audience may register for an account using django-allauth. Once registered they are automatically assigned to a custom 'Author' group. Authors are able to add a 'Profile' page followed by as many 'stories' or articles as they want. Stories are a subchild of profile so the URL looks like this: website.com/some_user/some_user_story.

This works great as the 'authors' are only able to create, edit and view the pages I want them too. But when adding images to their story pages via the image chooser, they are shown every image in the 'Authors' collection. This won't work as they must see only their uploaded images.

It's my understanding that what I need is not officially supported out of the box. However I checked the database tables and the **wagtailimages_image** table does indeed track **uploaded_by_user_id**.

Is there a class, method, hook or signal I can override to intercept and query the database in order to created the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is indeed a hook already in place for this. I ended up implementing the construct_image_chooser_queryset hook. The documentation is here: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5/reference/hooks.html#construct-image-chooser-queryset

In the project I have an app called 'dashboard' where I have all the code for customizing the Wagtail admin. In that app I created a wagtail_hooks.py file and added this code:

```
# Filter images in the image_chooser based on user
@hooks.register('construct_image_chooser_queryset')
def filter_images_by_user(images, request):
    images = images.filter(uploaded_by_user=request.user)

    return images
```

To finish up, I created a new image collection for the 'Authors' group. Then in the 'Author' group settings added that image collection and assigned it the 'add' permission.

Now when users add photos or use the image chooser, they see only the images they uploaded.

Comment: Yes, I have similar requirements and this hook works very well with chooser. Your trick with "add" permission works. Images gallery works in the way that user can see/edit/delete all images he/she owns without any permissions. "Add" permission allows user to able to add images. "Edit" means you can edit any image not just yours (which could be confusing) that's why it should NOT be checked for Author role.